# Disable Orbeon "as you type" validation for empty (never filled) fields?

Tags: jquery, validation, orbeon

As Orbeon forms normally operate, when a user **changes** from one field to another, the validation of the first field gets triggered, which is totally ok in general.

I'm facing a requirement that as-you-type validation (required fields) should **not** be performed for those fields **which were and remained empty**, i.e. if a user loads the form and only clicks in and out of the field, or moves over it by Tab.

So in case those fields remain empty, they will be validated at the end, when the user submits the entire form.

Is there a possibility to limit Orbeon as-you-type validation like that, not do it for empty fields?

Comment: See my answer below. Would this work for the use case you have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you can't switch to the behavior you're describing, say, by setting a property. But I see how it could make sense, in some cases. As you said, the idea is that you wouldn't show errors for a field if the user never typed anything in it. For instance, with a required field:

1. The user tabs in, doesn't type anything, and tabs out ⇒ no error shown (while right now, an error would be shown).
2. The user sets the focus back in the field, types something, tabs out ⇒ no error is shown (obviously, since a value was provided).
3. The user deletes the value in the field, tabs out ⇒ error shows (this even if the field is empty now, because the user had entered a value).
   And in all cases, all errors show on save/submit, as they do now.

Implementing this, could be done by changing, in the XForms engine, the notion of "visited" to match the above description. The error summary would be updated accordingly, as it uses `xxf:visited()` to decide which errors to show.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly the way it would work in the case I described. I'm not familiar with the XForms engine into much detail though, is this something which I could adjust by myself, or is it something which should be enhanced on a larger scale?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is trivial but it should be doable if you're comfortable trying to do some changes in the Java/Scala codebase. You'll let us know if you'd like to have some pointers on where to look.

Comment: It would be great if you could give me some pointers, I would try to adjust it if I can. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For this, you'll first need to build your own war of Orbeon Forms. You can find more info on http://doc.orbeon.com/contributors/building-orbeon-forms.html. Let me know if you're having any trouble with this. Once it is running, `VisitableTrait.scala` is a good starting point. In `performTargetAction` the code marks the component as visited on `DOMFocusOutEvent` and `XXFormsBlurEvent`. Instead, I'd try to make it visited on `XFormsValueChangeEvent`. If that works, then it would be good to have a property to choose which "visited behavior" one wants.